# How to undo accidental RAID initalization operation (recover data)?

Tags: data-recovery, raid-1

**Summary of the problem:**
 I have two disks re-configured as RAID 1. instead of copying the data to the empty disk, it deleted the data from the non-empty disk.

**Here's what happened:**
 1. In the last few days, I reinstalled Windows 8 twice.
 2. I had 2 disks configured as RAID 1 and 1 SSD contained the OS.
 3. While reinstalling Windows 8 (1st time) on the SSD, I might have removed the RAID configurations from BIOS.
 4. I made changes to the RAID disk.
 5. I reinstalled Windows 8.
 6. I noticed I see 3 disks (1 SSD, RAID-disk1, RAID-disk2)
 7. RAID-disk1 was updated to my last changes (done after installing Windows 8 for the 1st time)
 8. RAID-disk2 was updated to BEFORE installing Windows 8.
 9. I formatted RAID-disk2
 10. I set SATA configuration to RAID in BIOS.
 11. After restart, the disks was automatically configured as RAID and with status rebuild.
 12. In Windows 8 I get both disks as EMPTY!

**How do I restore the data?**

Comment: I'm guessing you didn't make a backup before doing this crazy stuff eh?  There are [many posts on here about recovering data](http://superuser.com/questions/tagged/data-recovery) from accidental overwrites.  What have you tried already?

Comment: Usually, if you use the BIOS to initialize the RAID it will just the RAID volume (AKA both drives).  For BIOS-based RAID like this, there is usually (also) an OS utility that allows you to create arrays and add disks (etc.).  When using that utility, you are given the option to select a drive you want to keep data from.

Comment: Okay, Then what do you suggest?   The first thing I did was to remove the raid configurations from the bios.

Comment: You've already re-initialized the RAID volume which killed the data, so you can't "undo it", just hope you can recover the data via some other means.  I suggest you read many of the suggested 'related' posts, and attempt some things that look good to you, and come back with specific questions, or at least come back and edit your question to show that you did some research and tried some things on your own.

Comment: Okay, I have an update:  I downloaded a software named "GetDataBack" and I was able to recover my data from both disks!!